Can axios call handle different response types?
I have an axios call as below
return axios.post(url, data, headObj)
.catch(err => {
return err.response;
});
Now there are 2 scenarios for the same endpoint;

If it is success response, I get a blob output (excel file)
If it is failure, I get an error JSON

How do I handle both the cases with the axios call ?

What is your exact problem with handling those two cases?

My issue is handling different response types for the same endpoint call...So for error case, it would be JSON response type V/s for success, it would be a file download (i.e. blob response type)

Try-catch works well for this:
const fetchFile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(url, data, headObj)
      if (response.data) {
        // success
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      // error
    }
  }


Actually in case of error, it is not exactly an HTTP error, but an error like data not found for the range/criteria...and that would be JSON error response type V/s for success, it would be a file download (i.e. blob response type)

Pls let me know based on the above scenarios
